# How to install .apk files that i have copied from my pc to phone

Tags: android

I have developed an simple android application that says hello. Now i have transferred my whole project into SDCard. while browsing my files on phone using astro file manager i am unable to view my .apk files. How can i install my application in my mobile now. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is a programming question, but I'll try to answer it.

To install your application to a device you don't need to copy all the project files on your phone, you just need the `.apk` file, which is located in the `bin` folder of your project. When you've copied the `.apk` file, you just can click on it in the ASTRO file manager and you'll be prompted to install the application. That's it!

Comment: Ok i've done what you said.I copied the hello.apk file into the sdcard and browsed it using officesuite. But it is not showing the .apk file anywhere

Comment: @user609282, Maybe should google for some tutorials? I really don't know why your phone won't see the apk file

Comment: do i need any other special installer to install .apk files and i am using alcatel 809D android mobile phone

Answer (score 2):

You may need to adjust your settings to allow install from unknown sources.

From your launcher (and this may vary, but should help):

1. Menu
2. Settings
3. Applications
4. Check the "Unknown sources" item
5. Try again!

Answer (score 0):

You can install the .apk file using adb.exe also (Located in your Android SDK folder under 'platform-tools') through the command line.

To do so, just type: adb install c:\pathtoapkfile\apkfilename.apk

Make sure you repalce 'pathtoapkfile' and 'apkfilename' with the appropriate path and apk file name.

This will install the apk on your phone without having to first transfer it to the device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a decent question about programming, well, however, I still want to answer this.
Generally, you can connect your phone to PC with an usb cable, then in Eclipse, you can select the device (perhaps you have to install the proper drive for your phone) to run the project; thus, eclipse will automatically generate the apk file and install it on the phone.

Also, you can copy the apk file to SD card, and then you can select it in File Manager(original android device doesn't provide a file manager. You may need a third-party file manager) and install. In this case, you should follow kiswa's instructions to enable the device to install third-party app.